# Why the defined path is used as file name when I transfer files through scp to a Windows host?

Tags: command-line, windows, quoting, filenames, scp

When trying to copy a file from Linux (Raspbian to be precise, though I don't think it matters) to Windows using SCP:

```
scp a.txt {user}@{ip}:\C\Users\{user}\a.txt
```

The file is copied, but to `C:\Users\{user}\CUsers{user}a.txt`.

It looks as if I need to escape the '\' somehow, but couldn't figure out how.

Comment: try forward slashes '/'
i think it must be something like this: scp a.txt user@ip:/C\:/Users/user/a.txt
but I am not sure about how to handle the C-drive with the ':' character

Comment: Which sshd product is in use on the Windows machine?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While I have never used `scp` on Windows, so I am only guessing, it certainly looks like the backslashes are ignored. Or, rather, as if they are taken as escape characters and, since they don't escape anything relevant, are being ignored. Consider this, on a Linux machine:

```
$ cd \usr\share
bash: cd: usrshare: No such file or directory
```

As you can see, the `\` were ignored and the path concatenated to a single string, just like what you describe above.

The default target location for `scp` is the user's home directory. Since that is `\C\Users\userName`, your attempt to specify a path is taken for a file name (`\C\Users\userName\a.txt` becomes `CUsersuserNamea.txt`) and the file is saved in the default location with that name: `C:\Users\userName\CUsersuserNamea.txt`.

A simple solution, in this case, would be to not specify a path:

```
scp a.txt user@ip:
```

Comment: Thanks, by combining your answer with @syss comment I've managed to get it working. For future reference, `scp user@ip:\C:/path/with/forward/slashes` does the trick.

Comment: @DeepSpace really? That's surprising. Did you also try `scp user@ip:/C:/path/with/forward/slashes`? With no `\` at all?

Comment: This is 100% due to the shell on the sending machine. `scp` is receiving `scp a.txt {user}@{ip}:CUsers{user}a.txt` as its arguments - it's never even seeing the backslashes.

Answer (score 2):

When playing with Windows paths, I would recommend to use relative one, such as (relative to home directory):

```
scp a.txt {user}@{ip}:a.txt
```